# uploading image not working in codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i'm new learning codeigniter 3, i have problem that i can't upload image in edit method. i'm really stuck, i already figure it out from the internet and documentation but there is no answer and my code still not working, when click submit button the method was success update to database but not with the image, here is my code

**My Controller**

```
public function edit()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Edit Profile';
        $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array(); //get username

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Full Name', 'required|trim');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
            $this->load->view('user/edit', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {

            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');

            //cek jika ada gambar yg akan diupload
            $upload_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

            if ($upload_image) {
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']     = '2048';
                $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/profile/';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
                    $new_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                    $this->db->set('image', $new_image);
                } else {
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
            }


            $this->db->set('name', $name);
            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $this->db->update('user');

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your profile has been updated</div>');
            redirect('user');
        }
    }
```

**My Views**

```
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('user/edit'); ?>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $user['email']; ?>" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Full Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $user['name']; ?>">
                    <?php echo form_error('name', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">Picture</div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/profile/') . $user['image']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row justify-content-end">

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change with your code like this

Change **view** with `name` attribute in your file `input` tag.

`<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">` to `<input type="file" name="userfile" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">`

and use `</form>` tag in last.

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('user/edit'); ?>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $user['email']; ?>" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $user['name']; ?>">
            <?php echo form_error('name', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Picture</div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/profile/') . $user['image']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" name="userfile" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row justify-content-end">

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And your **controller** change with bellow..

```
public function edit() {
    $data['title'] = 'Edit Profile';
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array(); //get username

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Full Name', 'required|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
       $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
       $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
       $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
       $this->load->view('user/edit', $data);
       $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
       $name = $this->input->post('name');
       $email = $this->input->post('email');

       $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
       $config['max_size']     = '2048';
       $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/profile/';
       
       $this->load->library('upload', $config);

       if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
           echo $this->upload->display_errors();
        } else {
           $new_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');
           
           $this->db->set('image', $new_image);
           $this->db->set('name', $name);
           $this->db->where('email', $email);
           $this->db->update('user');

           $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your profile has been updated</div>');
           
           redirect('user');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it solved now. it seems in my views file i forgot to add name attribut in input tag and </form> in the last

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with codeigniter, so maybe some of this is happening in your method calls, but I think your main problem is related to `$upload_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];` which only contains the file's name and no actual data.

1. the ['image'] part says the file was posted by the element named 'image' so in your html you need to name the file input with `name="image"`.
2. the uploaded file's actual data get stored as a file in php's `tmp` folder with a randomized name, so to access it you would need to use `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` and move it to your desired location (presumably `./assets/img/profile/`) using `move_upload_file()` before it will actually be considered "uploaded" to your server.  See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).
3. File uploads need rigorous validation to prevent malicious uploads, so validate both the user supplied name string `$_FILES['images']['name']`  and the file data itself.